# If I uninstall FIFA 15 will the save data be removed as well?

Tags: pc, fifa-15

If I uninstall FIFA 15 from my PC, then will my ultimate team club be all deleted? Along with my players and everything else?

Comment: Ultimate team is a server-side service.  You should be able to play on 2 different PC's and both seeing the same ultimate team, for example.  You may lose saves for the other game modes (single player career etc)... depending on the uninstaller (some will have an option to delete save games, others will delete everything, others will leave save files).  This is based on my experience with the console versions, I haven't tried for FIFA 15 on PC.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not.

Everything will be saved with your account on the server.